# How to localize ToggleSwitch on Windows Phone 7 (localizing Silverlight Toolkit)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

Silverlight Toolkit has a resource file named Resources.resx, which contains "On" and "Off" string states for the switch. But when I have added a corresponding localized resource, Resources.ru-RU.resx, it wasn't picked up by the localization (though the similar approach works for my own resources).

One way to do it is to create my own binding for the ToggleSwitch Content, but I was hoping for a non-coding solution. Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to name your resource file `ControlResources.ru-RU.resx` , see [Andrej Torzen's article](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2011/08/18/Localizing-the-August-2011-Windows-Phone-Toolkit.aspx) on the subject.

Comment: But it does not. Maybe I should do something else besides creating Resources.ru-RU.resx

Comment: Oh right, the name needs to be ControlResources.ru-RU.resx, not Resources, see http://tozon.info/blog/post/2011/08/18/Localizing-the-August-2011-Windows-Phone-Toolkit.aspx , if it works I'll update the answer with it.

Comment: This works for everything except for "On"/"Off" labels for ToggleSwitch - by some reason they are not in the ControlResources.resx file, but in Resources.resx, which is in "Properties" folder. Maybe Jeff thought "On"/"Off" shouldn't be localized? Anyway, good answer.

Comment: You could always recompile the SL Toolkit yourself, with that fix. Or create a bug-report on codeplex.

Comment: By the way this was filed as a bug on CodePlex (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/10164) and I've recently checked in a fix for the ToggleSwitch resources not being in the correct location.

Answer (score 6):

Localize ToggleSwitch in Silverlight Toolkit can be achived via DataTemplate

```
    <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="MySwitch" Header="Localized Switch">  
        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>  
            <DataTemplate>  
                <ContentControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"   
                    Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Switch}}"/>  
            </DataTemplate>  
        </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>  
    </toolkit:ToggleSwitch>
```

Declare an ValueConverter:

```
    public class BoolToSwitchConverter : IValueConverter  
    {  
        private string FalseValue = Resources.Off;  
        private string TrueValue  = Resources.On;  

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
        {  
            if (value == null)  
                return FalseValue;  
            else  
                return ("On".Equals(value)) ? TrueValue : FalseValue;  
        }  

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
               object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
        {  
            return value != null ? value.Equals(TrueValue) : false;  
        }  
    }
```

More details [here](http://blog.megahard.info/2011/09/localize-toggleswitch-in-silverlight.html).