# Localizing the default windows phone date picker

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, toolkit

I have localised the whole app but not able to localise the date picker. A bit of searchin in the forum gave me few answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266875/how-to-localize-toggleswitch-on-windows-phone-7-localizing-silverlight-toolkit)

but i cant find a properties folder with the resx for different lang for toolkit! I have jus added the toolkit reference in the solution explorer under reference and thats im able to access date picker. I have made a folder called toolkit.content to put the ok and cancel images.

so how do i add the resx for the toolkit date picker :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the source for the ToolKit and rebuild it with your localization

[WP7 ToolKit Source](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291#DownloadId=208985)

Comment: I did download the source, made modifications and now how do i add this toolkit? I cant find the dll :(

Comment: The source of the ToolKit build to the root parent. So wherever you extracted the source code is a Bin folder. It should be in a Debug or Release folder in there

Comment: i fixed it.  This is a useful blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/12/20/quot-and-she-d-say-can-you-see-what-i-m-saying-quot-how-to-localize-a-windows-phone-7-application-that-uses-the-windows-phone-toolkit-into-different-languages.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a custom control which inherits from the original DatePicker.

```
 public class MyDatePicker : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePicker
{
    public string PickerPageHeader
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PickerPageHeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PickerPageHeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for PickerPageHeader.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PickerPageHeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PickerPageHeader", typeof(string), typeof(MyDatePicker)
        , new PropertyMetadata("Choose date text in your language"));

    public MyDatePicker()
    {
        base.PickerPageUri = new Uri("/Sample;component/CustomControls/MyDatePickerPage.xaml?Header=" + PickerPageHeader, UriKind.Relative);
       //Don't forget to change the project name and xaml location
    }
}
```

And create picker page xaml file in a CustomControls folder:

```
<toolkit:DatePickerPage
x:Class="Sample.MyDatePickerPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
/>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MyDatePickerPage : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.DatePickerPage
{
    public MyDatePickerPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        foreach (var item in base.ApplicationBar.Buttons)
        {
            IApplicationBarIconButton button = item as IApplicationBarIconButton;
            if (null != button)
            {
                if ("DONE" == button.Text.ToUpper())
                {
                    button.Text = "done in your language";
                }
                else if ("CANCEL" == button.Text.ToUpper())
                {
                    button.Text = "cancel in your language";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        (base.FindName("HeaderTitle") as TextBlock).Text = e.Uri.OriginalString.Substring(e.Uri.OriginalString.IndexOf("Header=") + 7);
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple: Parameter - Language.
Xaml code:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Language="ru-RU" Margin="-12, 0" Value="{Binding BirthDate, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```